# Installing with magento2 Composer - php extensions: ext-mcrypt * and ext-intl * missing

Tags: php, magento2

I have tried to install magento2 in ubuntu 16.04 machine. I have followed [these](https://gotechnies.com/install-magento2-ubuntu-lts-16-04/) steps for install magento. When install composer then show these problems

```
 Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-gd * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
 Problem 2
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mcrypt extension.
```

How to solve these problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these command in your shell

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
sudo apt-get install php7.0-ext-mcrypt
```

then try again install composer

```
composer install
```